# Evaluation of the magnitude of fundamental vector product

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with the evaluation of the magnitude of this vector product. Is it the positive square root of the sum of the squares of the components of this product? If  not so , please help me to know.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty hard to read. So here's [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 101: to get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}$, you type `$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}$`. To get $\|\vec a\|^2 = a^2 = \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a$, you type `$\|\vec a\|^2 = a^2 = \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a$`. And to get $$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix}$$ you type `$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix}$$`. See if you can edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The magnitude of a vector of functions is computed the same way as a magnitude of a vector of scalars.

$${\bf r}(u,v) = (u+v){\bf i}+(u^2+v^2){\bf j}+(u^3+v^3){\bf k}$$

$${\bf r}_u = {\bf i}+2u{\bf j}+3u^2{\bf k} \qquad {\bf r}_v = {\bf i}+2v{\bf j}+3v^2{\bf k}$$

$${\bf r}_u \times {\bf r}_v = \begin{vmatrix} {\bf i} & {\bf j} & {\bf k} \\ 1 & 2u & 3u^2 \\ 1 & 2v & 3v^2 \end{vmatrix} = (6uv^2-6u^2v){\bf i}-(3v^2-3u^2){\bf j}+(2v-2u){\bf k}$$

$$\| {\bf r}_u \times {\bf r}_v \| = \sqrt{(6uv^2-6u^2v)^2+(3v^2-3u^2)^2+(2v-2u)^2}$$

The final expression ?might? simplify...I'm not going to do it though.

Comment: I guess there is no further simplification required.